# Passing Data To Delegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller, delegates

I have a bunch of outlets in a controller object that another controller needs to be passed. If it was only 2 or 3 values, I'd just pass them as parameters to the delegate method (not directly the outlets, but by copying the value to variables)

However, there are quite a few. What is the best way to handle this? I see three approaches:

- I could create a new object that holds all these properties and pass that.
- I could just pass the controller in the delegate method `[self.delegate didClickDone:self]`. The problem with this approach is this: am I allowed to access another controller's outlets from the outside?
- I could follow the 2nd option but copy every outlet's value to a property and allow the other controller to access them via accessor methods.

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always allowed to do what you allow yourself. However some approaches may prevent Apple from accepting your App for the Appstore. This is not the case here ;)

If there are many values to pass I'd go for

- An **array** if the passed objects contained are of the same type/kind
- Use a **data class** if the values are heterogeneous in nature. Like in [Refactoring](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#refactoring) by M.Fowler -> Introduce Parameter Object (page 295).

The dirty way would be, as you suggested, to open the Outlets to other instances than the view controller itself. Prevent that nosy behaviour of other classes.

Comment: Well, the objects are basically mixed. They're just data from the window that the controller owns. Some are strings, some numbers and some BOOLs. I'm guessing I should just make a new object called "Parameters" and pass that to the delegate method?

Is it also wise to pass the `parameters` object to the model of the program as well? As that is what the delegate method in the other controller will eventually do.

Comment: @Saad Abbasi I'd even go as far as: update your model, then don't pass the data as an object or array, and let your other instance access the model! As the model should hold the current state.

Comment: Trying to make sense of what you said here: Instead of passing `parameter`, I should just have a property in the controller which points to the model of the program. Once the controller has the values from its window it should directly notify the model and not go through the other controller? I feel like I'm completely off base here and not understanding what you mean. To be precise, I have two controllers: `SheetController` and `AppController`. The former's purpose is to handle a sheet and return the data to whoever called the sheet and I was doing that via delegates.

Comment: @Saad Abbasi alright. I meant, if you have a model which you update anyway, do it first and then let the other controller who is in need of the data just "ask" the model, don't pass the data twice. However I think in this case using delegation looks like a good way.